# Memoize not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I'm currently learning about memoization. As a simple exercise I implemented memoization with a fibonacci. However I'm having problems as to why when I do not rename the memoized function it takes slower to complete than when I rename it. Take a look at the code.

This doesn't work correctly and doesn't cache correctly.

```
function memoize(func) {
  const cache = {};

  return function(args) {
    const cacheKeys = Object.keys(cache).map(el => +el);
    if (cacheKeys.includes(args)) {
      return cache[args];
    }
    cache[args] = func(args);
    return cache[args];
  };
}

function wrapped_fibonacci(n) {
  if (n <= 2) {
    return 1;
  }
  return wrapped_fibonacci(n - 1) + wrapped_fibonacci(n - 2);
}

const fibonacci = memoize(wrapped_fibonacci); // <== I do not rename the function.

for (let i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {
  console.log(fibonacci(i));
}
```

However, when I write my code like this. It works correctly and is performant

```
function memoize(func) {
  const cache = {};

  return function(args) {
    const cacheKeys = Object.keys(cache).map(el => +el);
    if (cacheKeys.includes(args)) {
      return cache[args];
    }
    cache[args] = func(args);
    return cache[args];
  };
}

function fibonacci(n) {
  if (n <= 2) {
    return 1;
  }
  return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}

fibonacci = memoize(fibonacci); //<== I rename the function

for (let i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {
  console.log(fibonacci(i));
}
```

As you can see. I just reassigned the function name.
I'm doing these tests on node.js v8.3.0

The results of the first is as such.

```
time node fib.js

real    0m2.413s                                                                                                       │~                                                                                                                     
user    0m2.400s                                                                                                       │~                                                                                                                     
sys     0m0.008s
```

The results of the second goes as such

```
time node fib.js

real    0m0.263s                                                                                                       │~                                                                                                                     
user    0m0.252s                                                                                                       │~                                                                                                                     
sys     0m0.008s
```

**THATS 1.8S DIFFERENCE**

Anyone able to shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the working example, you're replacing `fibonacci` with a memoized function also called `fibonacci`. The recursive calls are using this memoized function, because `fibonacci-the-original` was replaced by `fibonacci-the-memoized`.

In the non-working example, you're creating a memoized function `fibonacci` from `wrapped_fibonacci`, but that function still calls `wrapped_fibonacci`, the *unmemoized* original, recursively.

If you'd also replace `wrapped_fibonacci`, it would speed up again:

```
const fibonacci = wrapped_fibonacci = memoize(wrapped_fibonacci)
```

Comment: This make perfect sense! Thank you for your insite!